# Double cannot be dereferenced [Arraylist]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Don't know how to solve this error at all. Trying create an average by using Array list. The second list of code is the (tester main[]). As you can see the  ArrayList has been created and the array values. ( Don't know if there is a separate tag of arraylist and array so I'm posting in both.)

```
**
 * A mutator method which calculates the average annual electricity bill.
 * @param monthlyBill an ArrayList containing the monthly bills for home electricity use.
 * @return the average monthly electricity bill.
 */
public double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill)
{
    double sum=0;
    if (!monthlyBill.isEmpty())
    {
    for (double month: monthlyBill  )
    {
        sum+=month;
    }

    return (sum.doubleValue())/ monthlyBill.size();
}
 }
```

---

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) 
 {
CO2FromElectricity CO2 = new CO2FromElectricity();

        ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill = new ArrayList<Double>();


        monthlyBill.add(279.41);
        monthlyBill.add(238.03);
        monthlyBill.add(248.64);
        monthlyBill.add(258.73);
        monthlyBill.add(395.48);
        monthlyBill.add(419.91);
        monthlyBill.add(431.15);
        monthlyBill.add(407.56);
        monthlyBill.add(417.14);
        monthlyBill.add(308.35);
        monthlyBill.add(337.91);
        monthlyBill.add(320.77);
```

Comment: What do you think this `sum.doubleValue()` does?

Comment: It gives me a primitive data type @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @Galaga It's already a primitive data type.

Comment: The primitive data type of what? What type is the `sum` variable?

Comment: I don't see any question in here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis A primitive double

Comment: Do primitives have methods?

Comment: Might as well close this post because I'm not informative of the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No they do not.

Comment: Then is it possible to invoke the method `doubleValue()` on the variable `sum`? And why would you, `sum` is already type `double`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, and thank you for being patient with me. Most people just get angry about the question and close the question do to my incompetence of posting in this forum.

Comment: We (I do too) get mad because we feel that people that ask elementary questions like this one don't put the effort to look it up themselves.  Java gives some pretty good error messages. Before posting, always try to search for the error message online. You'll probably find an answer faster than it would take to write your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a brace (you didn't close your `if`), and your `sum.doubleValue()` is incorrect (because `sum` is already a primitive "double").

```
public double calcAverageBill(java.util.List<Double> monthlyBill) {
  double sum = 0;
  if (!monthlyBill.isEmpty()) {
    for (double month : monthlyBill) {
      sum += month;
    }
  }
  return (sum / monthlyBill.size());
}
```

Comment: No need to cast `monthlyBill.size()` to double here.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest form is just

```
// generic method to calculate an average of an Iterable/List of Double.
public static double average(Iterable<Double> nums) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double d : nums)
        sum += d;
    return sum / nums.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and the [stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class :

```
return monthlyBill == null ? 0 : monthlyBill.stream()
                                            .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                            .summaryStatistics()
                                            .getAverage();
```